CalcDistance Deprecated: How to Calculate Vector Distance in Milvus SDK?
I encountered an error when trying to calculate the distance between two vectors using the CalcDistance():
service unavailable: CalcDistance deprecated.

I am using milvus-sdk-go version v2.4.1 and standalone Milvus version v2.4.6.
Here is the code snippet:
go
vector1 := entity.NewColumnFloatVector("vector", 512, v1)
vectortwo := entity.NewColumnFloatVector("vector", 512, v2)
distance, err := mc.CalcDistance(ctx, param.ColName, []string{}, entity.L2, vector1, vector2)
if err != nil {
    slog.Error("calc distance error", slog.Any("err", err))
    return 0, err
}

Since the CalcDistance() function is deprecated, what is the recommended way to calculate the distance between two vectors using milvus-sdk-go? Are there alternative methods available?

The calcDistance interface has been removed from the milvus server side. Most of the SDK have removed this interface except the Go SDK, we will remove it later.
You can use python numpy to calculate distance between vectors easily:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/calculate-the-euclidean-distance-using-numpy/
